# how can i achieve autoscrolling list (like autoscrolling text in ads) in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How can I achieve a horizontally list (contains multiple containers) automatically scroll up  and down like something like [this link](http://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/scrolling-text.cfm)?
I already made the list the problem is how to achieve the auto scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Every label in Codename One supports this, it's called "tickering" and you can just call `startTicker()` to start the tickering for a label. You might also need `setTickerEnabled(true)`.